How to make a 45degree oblique cut
I have some uni project where we have to make these oblique cuts on different objects, and it would be amazing if I could double check my results with a 3D model.
So the goal is to apply this logic to more complex objects too (Pics for it to make sense)
Its almost like a bevel, but trough the whole object

I'd investigate using a Boolean Modifier for that.

Using the Boolean Modifier as @John Eason said in his comment, you could use a mesh plane rotated and located as needed for the cutter.
I have made an object similar to the image showing Fig 11i. Note that the axes I use may differ from your object's orientation.
Add a mesh plane, Using Global Transformation Orientation rotate it on the X axis 45 degrees:


Then rotate the plane on the Y axis 45 degrees. Press Ctrl->A and apply rotation:

Move the plane on the Y axis to the location required:

With the object selected add a Boolean Modifier. Either click in the Object box and select the plane, or use the eyedropper and click it on the plane in the viewport. Select the Fast option:

Result after applying the Modifier:


amazing! Thats exactly what I needed! Thank you a lot:)
